# Canada post shipping method from canada to usa

Tags: codeigniter

I am creating web application in which shipping method which is canada post.
When shipping from canada to canada is working fine but when i shipped from canada to us then

> HTTP Response Status: 400
>   
> Error Code: 2695
>   
> Error Msg: Contact Phone number is         a required field.
>   
> Error Code: 1151
>   
> Error Msg: At least one line of Customs Description must be supplied.
>   
> Error Code: 8716
>   
> Error Msg: This product requires a valid value for Non-Delivery Handling.

is come.
My code is

```
<delivery-spec>
    <service-code>USA.XP</service-code>
    <sender>
        <company>ABC</company>
        <contact-phone>1 (xxx) xxx-xxxx</contact-phone>
        <address-details>
            <address-line-1>sender address</address-line-1>
            <city>MONTREAL</city>
            <prov-state>QC</prov-state>
            <postal-zip-code>xxxxx</postal-zip-code>
        </address-details>
    </sender>
    <destination>
        <name>John Doe</name>
        <company>ABC</company>
        <address-details>
            <address-line-1>Customer address</address-line-1>
            <city>Boston</city>
            <prov-state>MA</prov-state>
            <country-code>US</country-code>
            <postal-zip-code>xxxxx</postal-zip-code>
        </address-details>
    </destination>
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: You seem to be missing contact phone, Customs Description and Non-Delivery handling value seems to be incorrect.

These messages are only descrptive and don't give the correct field names and required value rules so you will have to do some digging in the code itself.

What you have posted is just order configuration and rules against what the order configuration failed.

Comment: i have added  <contact-phone>1 (xxx) xxx-xxxx</contact-phone>
Error Code: 2695
Error Code: 1151
is not available in document.

Comment: If you have added the field (which i actually saw) and the error still persist and doesn't say that maybe the format is incorrect then you are still probably missing the contact-phone field which in your case is probably ment for the destination part.

Furthermore you are still missing Customs description field and have incorrect value for Non-Delivery Handling.

Please atleast specify the module you are using to handle the orders.

Comment: i am using non-contract-shipment
i don't know which parameter for 
incorrect value for Non-Delivery Handling.

and i do not find any error code for custom description and phone number in the document

Comment: add "client-voice-number" parameter to destination with the clients phonenumber. This is required if the shipment is not domestic.

add <customs-description>Document</customs-description> (might need parent <item>).

As well add <option-code> which needs one of the following values in your case: Non-delivery handling codes
(required for some U.S.A. and international shipments)
RASE - Return at Sender’s Expense
RTS - Return to Sender
ABAN - Abandon

This question is VERY configuration and product specific. For my aswers I used the following page:

Comment: https://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/business/productsservices/developers/services/shippingmanifest/createshipment.jsf

To debug, try to match keywords in your errors to the page i posted. All the solutions can be figured out from that.

Comment: Thank you Martin , all is working fine now...

Answer (score 2):

If you receive this error:

```
Error Code: 2695
Error Msg: Contact Phone number is a required field.
```

then, you have to give the destination phone number:

```
destinationType.setClientVoiceNumber();
```

If you receive this error:

```
Error Code: 1151
Error Msg: At least one line of Customs Description must be supplied.
```

then, you have to give Customs Description under skuList

```
 SkuType.setCustomsDescription("material");
```

If you receive this error:

```
Error Code: 8716
Error Msg: This product requires a valid value for Non-Delivery Handling.
```

then,

```
opt.setOptionCode(option.getOptionCode());
list of options
RASE - Return at Sender’s Expense
RTS - Return to Sender
ABAN - Abandon
```